# Merging Edges In Blender

Tags: mesh, edges

I have two edges merging with each other. And I have to delete one edge. Pls tell me how to delete doubles

Comment: Can U share an image of whats happening to picturise the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender 2.83: In edit mode, select both edges, then click mesh\clean up\merge by distance.  Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance*. In Blender 2.79, it was <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thank You Zippy. You solved my problem

Comment: And Zippy the shortcut key is Alt + M.